# implementing Replace and Insert Buttons in Xcode/Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to xCode and confused about implementing the following two things to the replace button and insert button. Can someone please helpWhen you press the
“replace” button, the item selected in the picker should be replaced by the contents of the text field (blank if
nothing in the text field). When you press “insert”, the contents of the text field should be added to the data for
the picker, after the item currently selected, and the new, added, item should be shown in the picker as the
selected item (so the previously selected item would be immediately above it on the picker’s display at that
point).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var countryTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var selectButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var replaceButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var insertButton: UIButton!
let countries = ["USA", "MEXICO", "CANADA"]

var pickerView = UIPickerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    
    countryTextField.inputView = pickerView
    countryTextField.textAlignment = .center
}
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return countries.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return countries[row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        countryTextField.text = countries[row]
        countryTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create @IBAction for your Buttons from xib and add conditions accordingly. It will look like these-

```
@IBAction func insertAction(sender: UIButton){
  // write code for insert
}

@IBAction func replaceAction(sender: UIButton){
  // write code for replace
}
```

Comment: for insert and replace what would be the best way for the code? I know how to make it an IBAction and add the conditions.

Comment: for insert- countries.append( countryTextField.text )  and for replace.. you can replace countries element by .replace()

Comment: so it would just be countries.replace(uiPickerView)